# Whatsapp: "The download was unable to complete. Please try again later" for received voice messages and stickers

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Received voice notes or stickers don't download since a few days ago. The message shows a down-arrow icon, I click it and the circle around the icon spins for a few seconds and then shows this error:

[image]

Any ideas on what else to try for this error or how to debug it? This is what I have tried, to no avail:

- Internet connection is fine, other phones with Whatsapp using that connection work and every other app in this phone works fine. Tried WiFi and mobile data connection
- Phone date and time is correct
- Enough disk space
- Cleared Whatsapp cache and also wiped Android cache partition in recovery
- Whatsapp updated to last version
- Backup messages, uninstall Whatsapp, install Whatsapp, restore messages
- Tried with auto or manual download in Whatsapp options

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, it works using Whatsapp Web